# Assembly: leal from %esp to %eax

Tags: function, assembly, cpu-registers

I am trying to write a function with an unknown number of parameters in assembly, and at one point I wish to leal into %esp to fetch a byte at a certain offset on the stack. I am trying to do it this way:

```
movl        offset,%eax
leal        (%eax,%esp,1),%eax #
movb        %bl,(%eax)
```

Where offset is a 4 byte .long storing the offset of the most recently used argument in %esp. When assembling this piece of code, however, I get this message:

> Error: `(%eax,%esp,1)' is not a valid base/index expression

I am assembling for IA32 in kubuntu using GCC4.8. Gnu syntax, please :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it isn't valid, `esp` can not be used as an `index` register. The solution is simple though, because it is allowed as a `base`: just swap the operands and use `leal (%esp, %eax), %eax`. Alternatively, `add %esp, %eax`.

PS: `movb %bl,(%eax)` is a memory write, not a read, and you said you were trying to "fetch" a byte.

PS #2: of course you don't even need to calculate the address, you can do that in the mov instruction: `movb (%esp, %eax), %bl`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is 32 bit code, this isn't going to work because using esp as a base register uses ss (stack segement) instead of ds (data segment), and depending on the OS, ss and ds may not be logically equal. You could use

```
        movb    (%esp+offset), %bl
```

I don't know GNU syntax, but since the operand bl is a byte, you may be able to use "mov" instead of "movb" (if this is allowed with GNU syntax).